# React router scrolling to top to early

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When using React router, when you click a link it immediately shoots you to the top of the page and then loads in the next page.

The issue is that sometimes the loading of that next page takes 500ms - 1500ms. It creates this weird effect where you don't know the page is doing something and it seems like you've shot to the top of the page for no reason.

Although this effect is short (as the page loads in like 1s) it is still jarring.

I'm wondering if there is a way to mitigate this and only jump to top of the page when the client has got the date, html and css (images can load in later).

Are there callbacks for each loading event?

Or is this a dead end?

Thanks

Comment: I have never experienced this. Can you share your code or put it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is with `scroll` being managed in parent of both page (ie. `window`). If you manage the scroll within each component independently, it should not happen.